# Pycharm - Docker Image on Powerful Cloud Host as a Remote Interpreter?

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I want to use a Python Docker image running on a *powerful remote machine* (cloud or local network - but different from the one I sit in front of and installed PyCharm on) as PyCharm Python remote interpreter.

How do I set up the PyCharm access?

Do I need to run an ssh server on the docker image and treat it as a classic ssh remote interpreter while setting up port mapping on the cloud host machine?

The tutorials (e.g. https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/03/docker-compose-getting-flask-up-and-running/) apparently only apply to Docker and the Docker image running locally on the same machine as PyCharm, "localhost" or "127.0.0.1". I would like "some_machine_with_many_gpus.cloudapp.net:port" or similar. Is this possible?